# Completely disable form input fields without disabling every single element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a situation where I need to disable certain input fields in a form. There can be a lot of fields and it seems inefficient to disable every single element.

Is there a way to disable a group of elements by just placing 1 `disabled` tag somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just tested in current Chrome and can't find a way to tab to a disabled field.

Comment: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled> you tried this ?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it. https://4jolvy0rw.codesandbox.io/ Source: https://codesandbox.io/s/4jolvy0rw 

Browser: Chrome: 68.0.3440.106

Can you please also include the browser you are using to test this behavior?

Comment: may i know in which browser ?

Comment: I updated the question as it wasn't explained correctly

Answer (score 0):

The current should work:

`<input type="text" name="some_name" id="some_id" disabled>`

However, you said that didn't work for whatever reason. Try this:

`<input type="text" name="some_name" id="some_id" disabled onfocus="blur();">`

The function `blur();` is a built in JavaScript function that will un-focus (basically un-select) your target.

Comment: This `onfocus` has to be conditional or the OP will never be able to type in that field.

Comment: @Hardik Yes of course. I just want to emphasize on OP's question, which is *"Is there a way to disable a field and also disable the tab logic to that specific field?"*. OP clearly knew about the *disabled* attribute, and so I expect for him to know his own conditions for when the logic should be applied. Especially since no logic revolving that was addressed in the question.